# Consequences of physically moving My Documents folder to Desktop folder?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, junction, my-documents

What possible consequences (i.e. system instability / some programs failing) I can get if I'd create a junction point that points from My Documents to Desktop\My Documents?

Currently, I have two folders in my user directory:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ddd\Desktop
C:\Documents and Settings\ddd\My Documents
```

What I'd like to do is to create a junction point so I'd have all 'user' files in one folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ddd\Desktop
C:\Documents and Settings\ddd\My Documents -> C:\Documents and Settings\ddd\Desktop\My Documents
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that by the way? It is strictly NOT recommended to have much things on your desktop..keep it clean and tidy.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You already have a shortcut on your desktop to My Documents, what benefit do you hope to achieve?  Dragging and storing documents onto the desktop creates a hugely bloated profile and the desktop is not designed for such things.

According to Microsoft themselves:

> Don't store files on the desktop To improve your computer's
>   performance and find files more easily, it's best to store files in
>   the Documents folder rather than on the desktop.
>
> To access files from your desktop, create a desktop shortcut instead.
>   [Microsoft Desktop Tips & Tricks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Desktop-tips-and-tricks)

Found a good link.

Tweak UI is also an option.

[Change default XP Save In Location](http://xperiencexp.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-change-default-save-in-location.html)

> Through Registry:-
>
> ```
> Start>Run>Regedit>ok
> now navigate to:-
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\PlacesBar
> ```
>
> Note that by default Placesbar key is not present; you need to create
>   one. Create a String value for it named Place0. Place0 is the top-most
>   folder, it appears on the Open/Save As dialog. Type the folder name
>   with it's full path as the value of Place0. You can create similar
>   keys and values upto Place4.It will be like this:- Place0 Place1
>   Place2 Place3 Place4

Comment: thanks for the response. The benefit would be that I have all my files / folders stored in one directory, instead of two directories (Desktop directory + Desktop and My Documents directories).

Comment: Also, almost every new program I install, has the default 'Save to' directory defined as '%userprofile%\Desktop'. After some time I got tired of resetting this path in every program. Now I just save the files on the desktop and move the files to appropriate places with Total Commander. So, actually, maybe I should create a junction point like this: Desktop -> My Documents/Desktop. Either way, I'm curious about the possible consequences.

Comment: The claim is that the desktop must refresh the content every time a "call" is made.  When first loading Windows, for example, it loads all the icons, and all the folders.  It is just more crap for the memory to hold as references and is known to bog down systems.  I am not sure but it may act similar to prefetching...